# DRY React: To extend or not. My team seems to disagree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in a React project where we have custom styled form elements. A checkbox and a radiobutton are both rendered with:

1. A hidden `<input />` field.
2. A `<label>` that is connected to the `input`.
3. Based on the `:checked` pseudo-class it changes the rendered SVG element.
4. The only difference between a `checkbox` and `radio` is that CSS makes the radio buttons look rounded, and checkbox items are squared.
5. The browser takes care of only being able to select 1 radio item.

Now, the basic rendered HTML for this component is:

```
<input type={type} id={someid} />,
<label htmlFor={someid}>
  <div className="icon">
    {type === 'checkbox' && <CheckMark />}
    {type === 'radio' && <CircleMark />}
  </div>
  {label}
</label>
```

So I setup a radio.js React file. And my checkbox.js React file simply extends the radio:

```
export default class Checkbox extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <Radio {...this.props} type="checkbox" />;
  }
}
```

Same for the CSS files attached. They work using SASS, so my checkbox.sass basically does:

```
@extend .input__radio;
```

No code repetition. All is fine.

Now my colleague has copied the entire radio.js and radio.scss files and duplicated the code for the checkbox.js and checkbox.scss.

And my team 100% agrees with him, because: "They are different!"

The result is 72 lines of duplicate JS and 80 lines of duplicate CSS.

Who's right and who's wrong?

Comment: this will  probably be closed as primarily opinion based, i would say it depends on how resusable both codes are, and for more fair comparison you should post both, preferably in : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions I ask myself when deciding to share code (create an abstraction) are

1. What assumptions is this abstraction making?
2. How likely is it that these assumptions hold true and that use cases
   don't diverge? If it seems pretty likely that the things that are
   the same now will be different in a month, sharing the code now
   probably isn't a good idea. I generally try to be pretty pessimistic
   about this one, since software tends to diverge in ways that are
   difficult to predict.
3. How much am I benefiting from the abstraction? Is it going to significantly increase productivity?
4. How difficult would it be to unwind this abstraction if I end up with a use case that doesn't fit?

Unfortunately, there isn't really a magic formula from there, but I again try to be pretty pessimistic and avoid creating an abstraction if there are an red flags. It is much easier to create an abstraction later and replace repetitive code than it is to remove a bad abstraction.

In your case, my answers to the questions would be

1. The assumption being made is that radio and checkbox components are the same outside of the input type and the icon.
2. It seems pretty plausible that there may be additional differences down the line, since the checkbox and radio are different. You may want some styling or behavior for one but not the other, and that's easier to accomplish without the abstraction.
3. The benefit is pretty minimal. As you said, removes a small amount of duplication. If the two do end up needing to change in the same way, now have to make the update in two places instead of one.
4. Removing the abstraction would not be difficult, since the amount of shared code is pretty small and simple.

So the way I see it, the risk here of being in a bad situation caused by a bad abstraction is pretty low, but you also don't stand to benefit that much from it. I would personally lean towards not sharing code between these two, but I don't see it as a right/wrong scenario either; for me, the benefits don't justify its existence.

[This talk from a few years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4anAwXYqLG8) from Sebastian Markbåge of the React team really changed my outlook on abstraction and in general made me much more hesitant to reach for it.